# Syncing two Access databases - I can't see the data on the Master DB

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

I have one master db and slave dbs. I would like to sync those database, but two tables make lots of troubles.

By using an SQL Query, I get an error, because I used multi-valued fields. I cannot change the data structure and therefore I decided to "manually" loop through the recordsets and sync the tables. My code looks like this:

```
    sub UpdateTable()...
    .....
    Dim rstSlave, rstMaster as DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld as DAO.Field

    Set dbSlave = currentDB
    Set dbMaster = OpenDatabse("C:\Users\MyFile\Master_DB.accdb")
    Set rstSlave = dbSlave.OpenRecordset("tbl_Candidate")
    Set rstMaster = dbMaster.OpenRecordset("tbl_Candidate")
    Set rstSlave = dbSlave.OpenRecordset("tbl_Candidate")

    rstSlave.MoveFirst
    While Not rstSlave.EOF
       rstMaster.MoveFirst

       Do While Not rstMaster.EOF
          If rstMaster![ID] = rstSlave![ID] Then GoTo nextRecord
          rstMaster.MoveNext
       Loop

    With rstMaster
        .AddNew
        For Each fld in .Fields
            strFieldName = fld.Name
            fld.Value = rstSlave.Fields(strFieldName).Value
        Next fld
        .Update
    End With
   nextRecord:
   rstSlave.MoveNext
   Wend

   rstSlave.Close   
   rstMaster.Close

   Set rstSlave = Nothing
   Set rstMaster = Nothing
```

I cannot see the record in the master db. When debugging, I see that the ID of the record which was supposed to be transferred to the master db, already existed. Still couldn't find it in the master db when I opened the file.

Strangely it works the other way around. If I change something on the master db and sync it, I can see the changes on my slavedb.

Comment: You'll need some more code than that - your `GoTo` label isn't included at very least.

Comment: It is in my code, somehow it's gone here...I'll just update it :-/

Comment: Check if any field disallows duplicates or has other validation rules that would prohibit inserts.

Comment: What does _By using an SQL Query, I get an error, because I used multi-valued fields_ mean? I don't see anything in your VB that can't be done ten times faster and more reliably in T-SQL

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: This is Access, not SQL Server.

Comment: _I cannot change the data structure_ - but you should. Those multi-valued fields will cause you nothing but trouble; it is starting now, as you can see, and won't go away.

Comment: @Gustav OK I changed it and it works like a charm! Thank you!